# can we redirect user from webview to metro application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I want to redirect user from webview to my metro application? , I have the facility to change webview    html content (aspx)

Comment: If U want redirect Using URL, unfortunately not possible.
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN9 ]

Comment: I think you couldn't get my point , I am using webview in metro app and there we provide some template editor facility to user , so the problem is when user would finish his editing then he has to move next page  of app. How we solve this problem?

Comment: Are we talking about same Metro App? Do you just want to navigate to another page inside your current app?

Comment: Yes @Braim we are talking about metro app, and I want to navigate another page from webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can redirect the user to a 'fake url' of your choice (such as http://www.finished.com) when they are finished editing, then you would just need to listen to the LoadCompleted event of the WebView. In this event handler you can check the url to see if it matches your 'fake url' and if it does, then cancel the navigation and navigate to your xaml page.

```
    void webView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("finished.html"))
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you also couldn't get my point. I want to redirect from webview (such as e.g [www.myEditor.com]) to my metro app page main.xaml .

Note: I can edit site [www.myEditor.com] so if we have any oppertunity to put something in html content to redirect so we can do it.

Comment: I think what I described above will work for you, this is how I do it. Change your html to redirect to "http://www.finished.com" when you want to switch back to metro app page. Then in WebView.NavigationStarting event, check the url and if it is "http://www.finished.com", then switch to metro page.

Comment: great (y) I got your point but couldn't successful yet , can you send me the example or blog's link?

Comment: Correction: You need to use the NavigationFailed event (only windows phone has the NavigationStarting event). I edited the answer above to show this.

Comment: need your help
I have html page which is hosted here: [http://lcpscc.site50.net/win8/test.html]

this page only anchor tag which redirect it to google like this:
`<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>`

And Xaml code is here :
`<WebView x:Name="MyWebview" NavigationFailed="navigateToApp" /> `

And .cs code here:
  `void navigateToApp(object sender, WebViewNavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("https://www.google.com"))
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(test.Pages.main));
            }
        }`


is something wrong?

Comment: I was wrong, for WebView you need to use the 'LoadCompleted' event not the NavigationFailed event.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is having your Metro app handle a custom protocol like myprotocl://...
then have a link in your WebView to that protocol. That will open your metro app. 
see articles below 
[Registering a protocol handler in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559915/registering-a-protocol-handler-in-windows-8)

and this one

http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/10/28/launch-windows-8-metro-apps-from-a-desktop-shortcut-or-command-line/

you see how for example ebay:// is opening ebay app

Comment: , I am using webview in metro app and there we provide some template editor facility to user , so the problem is when user would finish his editing then he has to move next page of app. How we solve this problem?