# Windows 8 protocol handler limitations

Tags: windows, windows-8, registry, url-scheme, protocol-handler

When trying to register a custom protocol handler (like mailto etc.) I found out that there seem to be some limitations on Windows 8 concerning the length of the URL scheme string.

The [official standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1) says that a URL scheme must look like this:

```
scheme = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
```

But on Windows 8 I found that the following is the case:

**NOT working:**

```
a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a (25 chars, 13 letters)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa (14 chars, 14 letters)
aaaaaaaaaaaaa (13 chars, 13 letters)
```

**WORKING:**

```
a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a (23 chars, 12 letters)
aaaaaa.aaaaaa (13 chars, 12 letters)
aaaaaaaaaaaa (12 chars, 12 letters)
```

**My hypothesis** after some trying is that the URL scheme length must not exceed 12 characters excluding dots (I didn't try "+" and "-").

I am registering the URL scheme as described for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559915/registering-a-protocol-handler-in-windows-8/18496435#18496435)
(because I want my app to be listed in that Windows 8 modern UI "open with" dialog).

i.e. something like this (shortened):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myapp.ProtocolHandler
    (Default) = "urlscheme"
    Shell\Open\command
        (Default) = C:\path\to\my\app.exe %1
     
HKCU\SOFTWARE\mypublisher\myapp\Capabilities\URLAssociations
    urlscheme = myapp.ProtocolHandler
  
HKCU\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications
    mypublisher_myapp = Software\mypublisher\myapp\Capabilities
```

I couldn't find any official information about this limitation.

Can anybody explain me what is wrong here in my case or if that really is a limitation of the system?